# OCS Xmpp Iphone client

Tags: iphone, xmpp, ocs, xmppframework

I have `xmppframework` for ios. I was able to communicate with `GTalk` but I need to use this api for Microsoft OCS for internal application of my company. Our server has been configured with CWA.

```
NSString *pURL=@"im.name.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:pURL];

NSLog (@"%@", [url absoluteString]);

[xmppStream setHostName:[url absoluteString]];
[xmppStream setHostPort:443];
[xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"Domain\id"]];
password = @"password";
```

But i am getting the following error

```
SEND: <?xml version='1.0'?>
SEND: <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' to='companyname.com'>
xmppStream:didReceiveError: Error Domain=AsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=4 "Read operation timed out" UserInfo=0x157460 {NSLocalizedDescription=Read operation timed out}
---------- xmppStreamDidDisconnect: ----------
Unable to connect to server. Check xmppStream.hostName
```

It will be really helpful, if someone can assist me on this.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to file a feature request with Microsoft to ask them to implement [XMPP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120) if you want to use an XMPP library.  In other words, you're just completely barking up the wrong tree with XmppFramework.  One possible approach would be to port [libpurple](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple) to iOS.